# Action bar menu item icon with dropdown arrow style

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to modify the filter icon setting it an arrow like the share icon in the image. Just it. Someone help me out?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Ummm... open the image in an image editor and add the arrow?

Comment: Yeah...it could be a solution but, I want to do using layer list or with an specific style (share icon it's done via ShareActionProvider and I don't how it's done).